# Linear Algebra Proof (m×n matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be an ${m \times n}$  matrix and $(v_1, . . . , v_n)$ a basis of R<sup>n</sup>. Assume $(Av_1, . . . , Av_n)$ is linearly independent. Prove that null(A) = {0$_A$}.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n\in\ker A$ (why is it written like that?). Apply linearity and the only hypothesis you have to the identity $0=A(a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n)$ in order to prove that $a_1=\cdots=a_n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Let $T:v \mapsto Av$. Use rank-nullity i.e $\textbf{dim}(\textbf{im}(T)) + \textbf{dim}(\textbf{null}(T)) = \textbf{dim}(\mathbb{R}^n) = n$. Since $Av_j$'s are linearly independent, what is $\textbf{dim}(\textbf{im}(T))$?